# Chain Express methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express server with CRUD methods

I would that when `post` or `put` or `delete` are triggered , the `get` method is also run just after so that view get updated in my Front-end side

Here's my routes.js code

```
// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var express = require("express"); // call express
var NouvProj = require("../app/models/nouvProj");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router
  .route("/projets")

  // create a nouvProj (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/nouvProjs)
  .post(function(req, res, next) {
    var nouvProj = new NouvProj();
    // create a new instance of the nouvProj model

    nouvProj.nomProj = req.body.nomProj;
    nouvProj.leadProj = req.body.leadProj;
    nouvProj.descProj = req.body.descProj;
    nouvProj.BesProj = req.body.BesProj;
    nouvProj.pers = req.body.pers;
    nouvProj.backlog.fonctionnalite = req.body.Fonctionnalite;
    nouvProj.backlog.userStory = req.body.UserStory;
    // save the nouvProj and check for errors
    nouvProj.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        console.log("err");
      }
      res.json({
        message: "nouvProj created!"
      });
    });
    next();
  })

  .get(function(req, res) {
    NouvProj.find(function(err, nouvProj) {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      else {
        res.json(nouvProj);
        console.log(req.io);
      }
    });
  });
router
  .route("/nouvProjs/:nouvProj_id")

  // get the nouvProj with that id (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/nouvProjs/:nouvProj_id)
  .get(function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req.params.nouvProj_id);
    NouvProj.findById(req.params.nouvProj_id, function(err, nouvProj) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        //console.log(nouvProj);

        res.json(nouvProj);
      }
    });
  })
  .put(function(req, res) {
    NouvProj.findById(req.params.nouvProj_id, function(err, nouvProj) {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      nouvProj.nomProj = req.body.nomProj;
      nouvProj.leadProj = req.body.leadProj;
      nouvProj.descProj = req.body.descProj;
      nouvProj.BesProj = req.body.BesProj;
      nouvProj.pers = [{ name: req.body.name, poste: req.body.poste }];
      nouvProj.backlog.fonctionnalite = req.body.Fonctionnalite;
      nouvProj.backlog.userStory = req.body.UserStory;

      nouvProj.save(function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        res.json({
          message: "nouvProj updated!"
        });
      });
    });
  })

  .delete(function(req, res) {
    NouvProj.remove(
      {
        _id: req.params.nouvProj_id
      },
      function(err, nouvProj) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        res.json({
          message: "Successfully deleted"
        });
      }
    );
  });
module.exports = router;
```

Without `next()` middleware my application is posting and getting data. but when I add `next()`:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

starting at this part of code :

```
  res.json({
    message: "nouvProj created!"
  });
});
next();
```

How can I solve that and be able to update `get` method every add of data?

Comment: Are you trying to pass data from one middleware function to another?

Comment: I would create a data stream , execute `get` method after every `post` execution

Answer (score 1):

You can’t invoke `res.send()` `res.json()` `res.render()` etc. in a middleware function before calling `next()`. Express stops executing the chain once the response is invoked.

If you want to "chain" responses, you can use a library like request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to emit multiple HTTP calls. Here's one of the default examples:

```
request
  .get('http://example.com/img.png')
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png'
  })
  .pipe(request.put('http://example.com/img.png'))
```

Comment: I don't know if you have understood what I want . I would create a kind of stream, when Add a data, update the get method so that my front framework could listen to the changes .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send multiple responses to one request, that's just not how HTTP works, and that's why you're getting the error you're getting.

There are two ways that most folks use on APIs like this.  Either just return the object with the POST response (e.g. `res.json({ message: 'Success!', project: nouvProj });`) or else have the client make the GET query after it gets the success response.

Comment: I think that the first way is more appropriate, because there is no need for one other request.

Comment: @tariklefi It really depends on what's happening behind the scenes.  If the persistence is something that could take a while (e.g. processing video or the like), it's better to just respond that you got it, perhaps provide a link to where it'll eventually be, and then let the client find it later.